# add new line in my message inside a dialog <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

just wanted to ask how to put message in another line after the other. Here's my code in my program:

```
function isEmpty(field,name,minVal, maxVal){
  var msg ="";
  if (field.val() >= minVal || field.val() <= maxVal){
    if ( field.val().length == 0){ 
      msg=(name + ' is empty.\n');
    }
  }
  else{
    msg=(name + ' inputted is invalid or number is more than 1000. \n');
  }  
  return msg;
}

function validateTallyReq(par){
  var msg= "Please read the following:";

  msg += isEmpty($('#tallyPlankNo'),'Plank Number ',1,999) ;        
  msg += isEmpty($("#tallyThick"), 'Thickness value',.9,999);
  msg += isEmpty($("#tallyWidth"), 'Width Value',.9,999);
  msg += isEmpty($("#tallyLength"), 'Lenght Value',.9,999);
  msg += isEmpty($("#tallyQty"), 'Quantity',1,3);

  if (msg == "")  { 

  } else {
    showMessage(msg);    
  }
  return false; 
}
```

this outputs message in one line. What I want is the message to output like:

```
Please read the following:

Plank Number is empty. 
Thickness value is empty. 
Width Value is empty. 
Lenght Value inputted is invalid or number is more than 1000. 
Quantity is empty.
```

And one more question, I really dont know why it shows the length value is invalid though i dont input any value on it,. Please help.

**EDIT**

This is my showMessage function:

```
function showMessage(msg) {
  $('#dialog #message').text(msg);
  $('#dialog').dialog('open');
}
```

Comment: What does `showMessage()` do?

Comment: The `par` argument in `validateTallyReq(par)` is not being used.

Comment: please see my edit about the showMessage(). This is my function that will display the message inside my div.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding a `<br/>` to the message after each line.  That will work if the the `show()` method is doing something like `$("#displaydiv").html(msg);`

```
msg += "<br/>";
```

As for the unexpected `invalid` message, it looks like the logic in this conditional is faulty:

```
if (field.val() >= minVal || field.val() <= maxVal)
```

Try making it

```
if (field.val() >= minVal && field.val() <= maxVal)
```

Comment: If I will use this, `if (field.val() >= minVal && field.val() <= maxVal)` will output this `... inputted is invalid or number is more than 1000.`, though there is no input value.

Comment: And thank you by the way, for the tip you gave me `.html(msg)`. The message is working now.

Comment: Good point.  When you call `field.val()`, you're getting back a string.  But to use the `<=` and `>=` operators, you need to change that string to a number: `var num = parseInt(field.val(), 10);`  The `10` is the index, meaning base 10.

Comment: Actually it looks like you're using floating point numbers, not integers, so you should probably use `var num = parseFloat(field.val());`  See here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseFloat.asp

Comment: bbg, Thank you for the link. It helps me with this. Problem solved.

Comment: I had to use `<br>`; using `<br/>` is showing the text `<br/>` instead of a line break - weird ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the `\n` with `<br/>` since you are displaying via HTML.

Comment: It still dont work. The <br/> will display just like an ordinary text after each message. If I will use 'alert', it will go next line using that '\n', but no effect with my showMessageFunction.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might fix both of your

```
function isEmpty(field,name,minVal,maxVal) {
    var msg ="";
    if (field.val().length == 0) { 
        msg = name + ' is empty.<br/>';
    } else if (field.val() < minVal || field.val() > maxVal) {
        msg = name + ' must be between ' + minVal + ' and ' + maxVal + '.<br/>';
    }  
    return msg;
}
```

Comment: It still dont work. The <br/> will display just like an ordinary text. If I will use 'alert', it will go next line using that '\n', but no effect with my showMessageFunction.